# Understanding Task vs Task<T> as a return type

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task

Apologies if this has been addressed somewhere, but it is quite overwhelming the amount of resources on the topic.

I wrote the following method that awaits on an async call

```
public async Task GetAllObjectsNames(string bucketName)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(bucketName))
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(bucketName), "bucket name can't be null or empty string");
    }

    var request = new ListObjectsRequest
    {
        BucketName = bucketName
    };

    await  s_client.ListObjectsAsync(request);
}
```

Working on wrapping my head around the difference between returning a `Task` and returning a `Task<T>`

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<string>> GetAllObjectsNames(string bucketName)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(bucketName))
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(bucketName), "bucket name can't be null or empty string");
    }

    var request = new ListObjectsRequest
    {
        BucketName = bucketName
    };

    var response = await s_client.ListObjectsAsync(request);

    return response.S3Objects.Select(o => o.Key);
}
```

Could someone chime in?

Comment: Task<T> returns a value. Task does not

Comment: And `Task<T>` inherits from `Task`

Comment: `Task` is some kind of `Task<void>`

Comment: See [Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task?view=netframework-4.8), [Task<TResult>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task-1?view=netframework-4.8), and [Task-based asynchronous pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/task-based-asynchronous-pattern-tap?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: From the documentation: A task that doesn't return a value is represented by the System.Threading.Tasks.Task class. A task that returns a value is represented by the System.Threading.Tasks.Task<TResult> class, which inherits from Task.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`Task` represents an operation which might be in progress, or might have been cancelled, faulted, or completed. A completed `Task` does not contain any sort of result, it just represents the fact that the operation has finished.

`Task<T>` also represents an operation which might be in progress, or might have been cancelled, faulted, or might have completed. However, a completed `Task<T>` will contain the result of that operation, which you can then read.

You can write:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<string>> GetAllObjectsNames(string bucketName)
// ...
var objects = await GetAllObjectsNames("Foo");
await GetAllObjectsNames("Foo"); // Throws away the result of the Task
```

However you can only write:

```
public async Task GetAllObjectsNames(string bucketName)
// ...
await GetAllObjectsNames("Foo");
```

The `Task` returned from this version of `GetAllObjectsNames` cannot contain a result, so you can only tell when that operation has finished - you cannot get a result out of it.

You might use `Task` as the return value from an `UploadObject` method - where you care when the upload operation finishes, but there's no result for you to read. You would probably use `Task<T>` for `GetAllObjectsNames`, since the point of that operation is to fetch some values for you to then use.

Conceptually it's the same as the difference between a method which returns `void` (does not return a result), or a method which returns anything else. Or the difference between `Action` and `Func<T>`.

Comment: Perfect, this makes sense. Somehow I forgot that void mounts to Task in parallel world. I am definitely hungry.

Answer (score 1):

`System.Threading.Tasks.Task<TResult>` represents an async operation which can return a value (of type TResult).

(If it helps, this is akin to `System.Func<…, TResult>`, which basically is an action that returns a value).

`System.Threading.Tasks.Task` represents an async operation (which does not return a value).

(Again, this is akin to `System.Action<…>`.)